# Count number of values in array with variables

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to count the number of times a certain value turns up in an array. Except this value will always increment by 1, and there is an unknown number of these values in the array.

Example:

```
$first = array( 'my-value-1','my-value-2','my-value-3' );

$second = array( 'my-value-1','my-value-2','my-value-3', 'my-value-4', 'my-value-5' );
```

My goal is to be able to retrieve a count of 3 for `$first` and a count of 5 for `$second` in the example above.

There may be other values in the array, but the only values I'm interested in counting are the ones that start with `my-value-`.

I won't know the number of the values in the array, but they will always start with `my-value-` with a number added to the end.

Is there a way to count the number of times `my-value-` shows up in the array with some sort of wildcard?

Comment: This seems like a simple combination of a **foreach** loop or **array_map** and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Standard PHP `count($arrayname)` give you how many occurances there are in an array

Comment: If you have something in the array that does not start with `my-value-` then it would have been useful to show that in the samples you provide

Comment: If you ask a good question there is more likelyhood of getting a good answer and we dont waste our time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regex to filter the array and count the values that match. You could also use `^` to force it to be at the beginning `^my-value-\d+`:

```
$count = count(preg_grep('/my-value-\d+/', $first));
```

You could also do it this way.  Again you could use `=== 0` instead to make it match at the beginning:

```
$count = count(array_filter($first, function($v) {
                                        return strpos($v, 'my-value-') !== false;
                                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick function to count values by providing a partial string and the target array.
Note: search is case-insensitive.

```
function countValues($prefix, $array) {
    return count(array_filter($array, function($item) use ($prefix) {
        return stripos($item, $prefix) !== false;
    }));
}
```

Usage:
`$count = countValues('my-value', $first);`

Answer (score -1):

According to your question, "they will always start with my-value- with a number added to the end." So you don't need a regex, just a count of the number of items in your array, using PHP's built-in count() function. Try:

```
<?php 
$first = array( 'my-value-1','my-value-2','my-value-3' );
$second = array( 'my-value-1','my-value-2','my-value-3', 'my-value-4', 'my-value-5' ); 

$size_of_first = count($first);
$size_of_first = count($first);

echo $size_of_first; //Will echo 3
echo $size_of_first; //Will echo 5

?>
```

Comment: There may be other values

Comment: Yes, this is the issue I'm facing is that there will be other values. The values I'm interested in counting will always start with `my-value-` though. I will clarify the original question.

Comment: @ScottD Well then show that possibility in your question. We are not **clairvoyant** we can only answer based on what is in the question

Comment: Then go with @AbraCadaver 's solution.